What does the statement: "$A$ is a square matrix and $\ker A^{n-1} \neq \ker A^n$ where $n≥2$" imply?
Currently going over
Given the square matrix $A$ and that $\ker(A^2) = \ker(A^3)$ does this imply that $\ker(A^3) = \ker(A^4)$?
What about the following statement: $A$ is a square matrix and $\ker A^{n-1} \neq \ker A^n$ where $n≥2$.
My understanding is that

The kernel of a homomorphism is reduced to 0 (or 1) if and only if the
homomorphism is injective, that is if the inverse image of every
element consists of a single element.

Am I missing more context to solve if the statement is true or false:  $\ker A^{m-1} \neq \ker A^m$ for all $1 < m≤n$?

What specifically do you mean by "solve"?

I will expand. Solve if the statement is true or false.

So you want to know whether $\ker(A^{n-1}) \neq \ker(A^n)$ implies that every other preceding kernel is also different?

yes, I am reading on kernels and invariant subspaces. I have no idea where to start to anwer this question from a test I got few years ago.

It certainly isn't true for all $A.$ Do you mean if under the condition that $\ker(A^2)\neq \ker(A^3)?$

Including this condition as well. But if we keep only this condition, does it change the answer?

You can borrow from the proof in the other question, and prove it via contradiction.
First, assume that for some $1 < m \leq n$, that $\ker(A^{m-1}) = \ker(A^m)$. So then $A^{m-1}x = 0 \iff A^m x = 0$.
Then we can look at $x \in \ker(A^n)$ and show that $x \in \ker(A^{n-1})$ and vice versa, proving that the two sets are subsets of each other, which means they must be equal.
But if the two kernels are mutual subsets, then they must be equal, which we know is not the case, and so our assumption must be false.
